# test if a method is called inside a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have this code inside `create` from some controller

```
if @company.save && ServiceCompany.create(service_id: params[:service_id], company_id: @company.id)
      update_vendor_on_customer_io
      sign_in(:company, @company)
      redirect_to edit_vendor_company_url(@company.secret)
    else
      render action: "new", layout: "assistant"
    end
```

I want to test with rspec if the `update_vendor_on_customer_io` is beign called. I tried something like this:

`expect(subject.create).to receive(:new_or_update_vendor).with(param)` but didn't worked. is it possible do test?

Comment: (can't check myself now) Let's say your controller is `CompaniesController` so I think you should expect that method `new_or_update_vendor` is called from instance of controller, it means `expect(CompaniesController.any_instance).to receive(:new_or_update_vendor).with(param)`. PS and do not forget t place expectation before triggering action `create`

Comment: Where is your update_vendor_on_customer_io located?
The basic idea is you expect(some_component).to receive(:method_name) and AFTERWARDS you do your "post create (...)" controller action call and it will tell you if the method wasn't called.

Comment: you guys got it right. that woulnd't be possible. I ended up testing just the create method and testing this `update_vendor_on_customer_io` on another spec